# Is it possible to extend a table header view so that it goes behind the first row of cells like a background?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, nstableviewheader

There are 2 different versions of app, one with the table header view on top of the cells.  The other version it's supposed to extend behind the first row of cells like a background, but still maintain its same starting position on top of the rows. Is this even possible? If not suggestions are welcome on how to create this type of effect.

This is the effect I'm trying to go for:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
set containerView object:

```
let tableBgView = UIView()
```

after that set your dummy header view:

```
let bgCell = UIView()
```

Now set tableView background color to .clear

```
tableView.backgroundColor = .clear
```

In cellForRowAt (or in your custom cell) set cell backgroundColor to .clear

```
cell.backgroundColor = .clear
```

In viewDidLoad set you objects property and tableView background view:

```
tableBgView.backgroundColor = .white
tableBgView.frame = view.bounds

bgCell.backgroundColor = .yourColor
bgCell.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
tableBgView.addSubview(bgCell)
```

now set auto layout of bgCell:

```
bgCell.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tableBgView.topAnchor).isActive = true
bgCell.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tableBgView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
bgCell.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tableBgView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
bgCell.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: yourCellHeight).isActive = true
```

add tableView bacgroundView:

```
tableView.backgroundView = tableBgView
```

This is the result:

[image]

**Update**

if you want tableView header too simply add:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 70
}
```

and create your tableViewHeader:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let myView = UIView()
    myView.backgroundColor = .yourColor
    
    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = "Header"
    label.textColor = .white
    label.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 20, weight: .semibold)
    label.textAlignment = .center
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    myView.addSubview(label)
    label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myView.topAnchor).isActive = true
    label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    label.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    label.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    
    return myView
}
```

And this is the result:

[image]

For image see the comment below..

[image]

Comment: This is good, but the header has an image background and whats needed is the cells are supposed to load in front of the image.  I added a pic to show what I mean, the cards you see are on the cell itself.

Comment: @SwiftyJD if I understand correctly, simply transform bgCell in a imageView let bgCell = UIImageView(), set the content mode of it bgCell.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill, set your imageView.image bgCell.image = UIImage(named: "yourImage"), remove tableView header and after play with the eightAnchor of bgCell... You see the result in my answer above...